# How can I customize an information bubble in React-chartjs2 when clicking a point?

Tags: react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Using the example from [there site](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/reactchartjs-react-chartjs-2-default-1695r?file=%2FApp.tsx%3A8%2C9) for a Line graph, it seems to support base information when hovering a point. Does anyone know how to customize this to using your own information? For example, in the example it says  "Dataset x: number", how can I change this to be, "On [X Value (The Date)], You were [Down/UP] Y value dollars".

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to find on the documentation because the word I needed to know was "tooltip".

Found here, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/html.html